# WPF BindingExpression UpdateSource not working

Tags: wpf

I have a Mainwindow with a label.

```
<Label 
    Name="RoundLabel" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    Content="{Binding Source={x:Static core:Supervisor.Simulator}, Path=Round, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}"
    />
```

In the code-behind there is a method to update the lablecontent

```
 public void updateRound()
    {
      BindingExpression binding = RoundLabel.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
        binding.UpdateSource();
    }
```

In another class I call `updateRound`

```
public int Round
    {
      get
      {
        return round.Value;
      }
      set
      {
        if (!(round.Value == value))
        {
          round.Value = value;
          App.Current.Dispatcher?.Invoke(() => (App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).updateRound());
        }
      }
```

So everytime the value of round changes it should be changed in the label.
There are no exceptions, but the roundnumber in the GUI isn't updatet.

Where is my error? Does anything miss?

Comment: `UpdateTarget()` should work ... but it is **really not** the way you make updates in wpf UI. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is your friend

Comment: Apparently you haven't understood how data binding works, especially not how a changed source property notifies a binding to update its target property. Binding.UpdateSource() is not what you need. Instead, implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the class that owns the source property. Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, UpdateTarget() works. I also tried INotifyPropertyChanged, but got some problems with the updateSourceTrigger...

Comment: You don't need to set UpdateSourceTrigger and Mode=TwoWay. That has no effect in your Binding. There is also no need to set the Label's DataContext when you explicitly set the Source of the Content Binding. Seriously, read the MSDN article. You're messing it all up otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifying a WPF Binding of a changed source property value is usually done by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface like this:

```
public class Simulator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int round;

    public int Round
    {
        get
        {
            return round;
        }
        set
        {
            if (round != value)
            {
                round = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                    this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Round)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now put an instance of your Simulator class into the `DataContext` of your Window, and bind a Label's `Content` like this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Simulator/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Round}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Set the property in code behind by accessing the object in the DataContext:

```
((Simulator)DataContext).Round = 42;
```